# SDK level 15 ApiDemos/OS/Sensors blurred image on Nexus S but not on emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-sensors, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, nexus-s

Typically, the ApiDemos/OS/Sensors application displays three circles denoting the current orientation. Why are these three Canvas drawn circles blurred when the application is built with SDK level 15 and run on my Nexus-S running OS 4.0.4? I've checked my Nexus-S 'Settings/Developer options' and the only developer option checked is 'USB debugging'. I tried toggling the 'Force GPU rendering' developer option but the blurring remains. I also looked at the Canvas drawings in the ApiDemos/Graphics applications built with SDK level 15 and noticed no blurring problem there. Is this blurring in the ApiDemos/OS/Sensors application built with SDK level 15 also happening on other phone models?

Below, the first screenshot is the emulator running ApiDemos built with SDK level 15 (OS 4.0.4), the second is the Nexus-S running ApiDemos built with SDK level 15, the third is the Nexus-S running ApiDemos built with SDK level 10 (0S 2.3.3).

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: i've tested it on many devices , and never saw such a thing . however , most of them didn't have ICS .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The unwanted blurring behavior in ApiDemos/OS/Sensors built with SDK level 15 and running on Nexus S was confirmed and solved by RichardC in this Google Groups android developer thread: https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en&fromgroups#!topic/android-developers/2DT6JaPszR0

In a nutshell, the ApiDemos/OS/Sensors application's drawing buffer complexity (that presumably increased the sensor data display rate) was not correctly handled by the hardware accelerator. RichardC offered two solutions: reduce the application's drawing buffer complexity or, in the manifest, disable the hardware acceleration for the ApiDemos/OS/Sensors application. (I chose the former and it didn't slow down the sensor data display rate.)